# Procedural Hair Texture, the stripes don’t follow the shape right

Tags: modeling, uv, topology, procedural, surface-deform

Im making a procedural hair texture with vertical stripes following the strand shape, but said shape is narrower at the top and bottom, and the stripes don’t narrow evenly for some reason. Instead there‘s a weird cut through the last quads, at which the stripes suddenly change direction, and it doesn’t look very organic. Can someone tell me if I can change that? The UVs are just a grid, perfect rectangles all the way.
[image: stripes going perfectly vertical while the hair shape is vertical, but going at weird angles when bottom edges are scaled out or inwards, almost as if the quads are cut into triangles]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quads are always made of 2 hidden triangles in 3D softwares, so when you deform the faces in the 3D view but not in the UV Editor (or vice versa) it will stretch the 2 triangles within the quads and give this kind of deformation. To fix that (or at least to make the triangulation effect unnoticeable) you need to subdivide your mesh (or give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier)